# A positive alternative to 'harp'

Tags: synonyms

To harp is to *talk or write persistently and tediously on (a particular topic).*

Example: "I don't want to harp on about the past"

Is there a similar, non-tedious equivalent?

Comment: See also *dwell*.

Comment: What did a (on-line) thesaurus suggest and what did you not like about their suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

She ***expatiated*** for hours on the subject of working-class novelists.

Comment: Interesting. Although, one of its synonyms is _dwell on_. I've always took that as a negative. How about you?

Answer (score 1):

[To dilate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dilate): ( from TFD)

> - To speak or write at great length on a subject;

also: [to tell](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tell)

> - To give a detailed account of; narrate: tell what happened.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is considered entirely positive, but **"gush"** is a word for excitedly speaking on a subject for a time.